# Why does hot steam produce MgO instead of Mg(OH)2?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, metal

**Background research**

- Magnesium hydroxide exists naturally as brucite ([source: wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_hydroxide#Preparation))
- Passing hot steam over magnesium produces magnesium oxide (source: [Edexcel's June 2014 Unit 2 exam (CH02_01): question 18](http://freeexampapers.com/?dir=A-Level/Chemistry/Edexcel/2014-Jun))

**Question**

Why doesn't magnesium hydroxide form when treated with hot steam, instead of magnesium oxide?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two steps in the process:

$\ce{Mg + H2O -> MgO + H2}$

and

$\ce{MgO + H2O <-> Mg(OH)2}$

The equilibrium point in the second step is dependent on the temperature. See file [Equilibrium Assemblages](http://www.nsm.buffalo.edu/courses/gly206/StableAssemblages.pdf) for more information.

Comment: The chemical equation has to be balanced

Answer (score 1):

$\ce{Mg(OH)2}$ decomposes at high temps into $\ce{MgO}$ and $\ce{H2O}$. To be exact, 350 C