# Balancing a reaction with unknown products

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

I'm given this equation in word form:

$$\ce{sodium (s) + water (aq) -> unknown~products (s/g/aq)}$$

and I have to convert this to a chemical equation. I understand how to covert this normally, that equation can hence be represented by:

$$\ce{Na + H2O -> unknown~products\:(s/g/aq)}$$

This is indeed a single displacement reaction so it should become (according to what I know so far) $\ce{Na2O + H2}$ but after doing some research, I got that it should be:

$$\ce{Na + H2O -> NaOH + \frac{1}{2}H2}$$ or $$\ce{2Na + 2H2O -> 2NaOH + H2}$$

I'm lost now, where did $\ce{NaOH}$ come from? Especially the H since there is no reason for hydrogen to be present.

Please explain why and how to balance this reaction or convert this and what factors to look at when dealing with these types of equations.

Comment: The Na2O is unstable so it would very quickly convert to the more stable NaOH.

Comment: Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/443/) and [this ‎one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/111/) on how to format your posts better.‎ Alternatively, visit [this chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27198/latex-mathjax-help) for further formatting guidance.

Comment: The hydrogen is created from the exothermic reaction between the highly reactive sodium metal and water.

Comment: @Joel But how can I identify when it does that? and where did H come from?

Comment: The H comes from the water, think about what happened to the water molecule that reacted with the sodium ion and left an oxygen atom , hence the speculation of sodium oxide formation, where did the hydrogens go?. Sorry identify when what does what?

Comment: If you did the reaction practically you can definetly observe the sodium reacting with the water, the pH of the water will turn alkaline as the sodium hydroxide is formed.

Comment: I don't really get it though :/... I thought single displacement would take the form of A + BC -> AB + C with no exceptions. Na+H2O... So Na bonds with oxygen right? And they form Na2O and O2 is left? @Joel

Comment: @Joel I think it's the same case with Potassium + Water but I don't know why

Comment: No, think if the sodium or potassium (as you just mentioned)  takes the oxygen from a water molecule (H2O) , hydrogen is left. Sorry I can't do the required format for any equations on my phone. Due to the fact that these oxides are so unstable , the product is just written as sodium hydroxide , using the thinking that there's no need to mention the intermediate sodium oxide .

Comment: Oh okay @Joel that makes a lot of sense. I have this question for a science lab, however we weren't taught this so should I keep the answer with OH? Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Sodium ion taking the oxygen atom or water molecule leaving oxygen atom ,  same thing ( sorry if it was confusing) .

Comment: It is correct both ways (to write the intermediate or not) but more conventionally written with the hydroxide byproduct as under normal conditions the oxide fully converts to the hydroxide so it is the end product.

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27393/why-does-hot-steam-produce-mgo-instead-of-mgoh2

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sodium(s)+water(aq)⟶Unknown Products(s/g/aq)

In this case you treat the hydrogen as a cation, or as a metal which is why it is displaced. Treat H2O as H(OH).

I know I have answered my own question but this is the answer I was looking for a long time ago.

Comment: This is unfortunately wrong. The reaction is not a displacement reaction. It is a redox reaction. One electron of sodium gets transferred to the hydrogen of water, which liberates a dihydrogen molecule.

Answer (score -2):

Water is normally a mix of hydroxide and hydrogen, at very dilute levels.  For example, neutral water (pH of 7) is 10-7 of OH- and H3O+ ions.  Add sodium and it combines with the OH-.  The loss of electrons by sodium are available to the hydrogen ions, which combine to make hydrogen gas.  Sodium in metal form is so reactive, it will sustain this reaction even at the low hydroxide levels in pure water, and even in slightly acidic seawater.

Comment: There are some pretty significant errors in your answer (including but not limited to the first sentence, especially regarding hydrogen).